# SharePoint query GetListItems return 0x80070093

Tags: sharepoint, soap

I want to get file list from SharePoint with this query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>Documents</listName>
            <query>
                <Query xmlns="">
                    <Where>
                       <Eq>
                           <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" />
                           <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
                       </Eq>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
            </query>
            <viewFields><ViewFields xmlns="" /></viewFields>
            <queryOptions>
                <QueryOptions xmlns="">
                    <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                    <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
                </QueryOptions>
            </queryOptions>
        </GetListItems>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But SharePoint return error message saying that the column number for research reach the administrator limit.

Could you help me please.

Comment: What's the version you're using?

Comment: De use sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem involves the List View Lookup threshold.
To increase that, you must

1. Go to Sharepoint central admin
2. Application management, and click on your web app
3. Under general settings, Resource throttling
4. Increase lookup threshold from 8 to X and View threshold if required

Comment: The error message does not look related to a malformed query but a configuration problem. Try increasing the threshold